# PluginOneSignal/PluginOneSignal.h' file not found

Tags: c++, cocos2d-android

****while debugging the project its showing plugin one signal not found and ninja build stopped command,**

**I tried everything, I installed ninja then also it's not working,**

In file included from C:\Users\Vaka\Desktop\cocosproject\proj.android\app\jni\hellocpp\main.cpp:30:
C:\Users\Vaka\Desktop\cocosproject\Classes\AppDelegate.h:29:10: fatal error: 'PluginOneSignal/PluginOneSignal.h' file not found`#include

android.mk file`

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := MyGame_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libMyGame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := /hellocpp/main.cpp \
../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
../../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -DSDKBOX_ENABLED
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -landroid \
-llog
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := PluginOneSignal \
sdkbox

# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_END


LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cc_static

# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_END

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH))

$(call import-module, cocos)
$(call import-module, ./sdkbox)
$(call import-module, ./PluginOneSignal)

# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_END
```

below is the CMAKELIST.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

set(APP_NAME cocos project)

project(${APP_NAME})

set(COCOS2DX_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cocos2d)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${COCOS2DX_ROOT_PATH}/cmake/Modules/)

include(CocosBuildSet)
add_subdirectory(${COCOS2DX_ROOT_PATH}/cocos ${ENGINE_BINARY_PATH}/cocos/core)

# record sources, headers, resources...
set(GAME_SOURCE)
set(GAME_HEADER)

set(GAME_RES_FOLDER
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Resources"
    )
if(APPLE OR WINDOWS)
    cocos_mark_multi_resources(common_res_files RES_TO "Resources" FOLDERS ${GAME_RES_FOLDER})
endif()

# add cross-platforms source files and header files 
list(APPEND GAME_SOURCE
     Classes/AppDelegate.cpp
     Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp
     )
list(APPEND GAME_HEADER
     Classes/AppDelegate.h
     Classes/HelloWorldScene.h
     )

if(ANDROID)
    # change APP_NAME to the share library name for Android, it's value depend on AndroidManifest.xml
    set(APP_NAME MyGame)
    list(APPEND GAME_SOURCE
         proj.android/app/jni/hellocpp/main.cpp
         )
elseif(LINUX)
    list(APPEND GAME_SOURCE
         proj.linux/main.cpp
         )
elseif(WINDOWS)
    list(APPEND GAME_HEADER
         proj.win32/main.h
         proj.win32/resource.h
         )
    list(APPEND GAME_SOURCE
         proj.win32/main.cpp
         proj.win32/game.rc
         ${common_res_files}
         )
elseif(APPLE)
    if(IOS)
        list(APPEND GAME_HEADER
             proj.ios_mac/ios/AppController.h
             proj.ios_mac/ios/RootViewController.h
             )
        set(APP_UI_RES
            proj.ios_mac/ios/LaunchScreen.storyboard
            proj.ios_mac/ios/LaunchScreenBackground.png
            proj.ios_mac/ios/Images.xcassets
            )
        list(APPEND GAME_SOURCE
             proj.ios_mac/ios/main.m
             proj.ios_mac/ios/AppController.mm
             proj.ios_mac/ios/RootViewController.mm
             proj.ios_mac/ios/Prefix.pch
             ${APP_UI_RES}
             )
    elseif(MACOSX)
        set(APP_UI_RES
            proj.ios_mac/mac/Icon.icns
            proj.ios_mac/mac/Info.plist
            )
        list(APPEND GAME_SOURCE
             proj.ios_mac/mac/main.cpp
             proj.ios_mac/mac/Prefix.pch
             ${APP_UI_RES}
             )
    endif()
    list(APPEND GAME_SOURCE ${common_res_files})
endif()

# mark app complie info and libs info
set(all_code_files
    ${GAME_HEADER}
    ${GAME_SOURCE}
    )
if(NOT ANDROID)
    add_executable(${APP_NAME} ${all_code_files})
else()
    add_library(${APP_NAME} SHARED ${all_code_files})
    add_subdirectory(${COCOS2DX_ROOT_PATH}/cocos/platform/android ${ENGINE_BINARY_PATH}/cocos/platform)
    target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} -Wl,--whole-archive cpp_android_spec -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
endif()

target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} cocos2d)
target_include_directories(${APP_NAME}
        PRIVATE Classes
        PRIVATE ${COCOS2DX_ROOT_PATH}/cocos/audio/include/
)

# mark app resources
setup_cocos_app_config(${APP_NAME})
if(APPLE)
    set_target_properties(${APP_NAME} PROPERTIES RESOURCE "${APP_UI_RES}")
    if(MACOSX)
        set_target_properties(${APP_NAME} PROPERTIES
                              MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/proj.ios_mac/mac/Info.plist"
                              )
    elseif(IOS)
        cocos_pak_xcode(${APP_NAME} INFO_PLIST "iOSBundleInfo.plist.in")
        set_xcode_property(${APP_NAME} ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME "AppIcon")
        set_xcode_property(${APP_NAME} DEVELOPMENT_TEAM "")
        set_xcode_property(${APP_NAME} CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer")
    endif()
elseif(WINDOWS)
    cocos_copy_target_dll(${APP_NAME})
endif()

if(LINUX OR WINDOWS)
    set(APP_RES_DIR "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${APP_NAME}>/Resources")
    cocos_copy_target_res(${APP_NAME} COPY_TO ${APP_RES_DIR} FOLDERS ${GAME_RES_FOLDER})
endif()
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with ninja. Do you have that header somewhere in your source tree? You will have to tell us what your directory structure looks like and.

Comment: Are you trying to integrate the onesignal sdk into a cocos2d application? Then definitely show us your directory tree and cmakelists.txt

Comment: then why ninja error is showing, can u pls tell

Comment: while debugging the project its showing ninja build subcommand failed

Comment: Because ninja is calling your compiler. The error is coming from your compiler, which is telling you that it does not know how to find that file. So either you do not have that file, or you do but forgot to tell the compiler where it is. Again, show us your directory tree and where that file is located.

Comment: android.proj->app>jni->pluginonesignal

Comment: yeah am trying to integrate the one signal SDK into cocos2d

Comment: Where is `pluginonesignal.h` in your source directory? And for the last time: Ninja is not responsible for the error, it is working fine. Your **compiler** is complaining about a missing file. Show us your `CMakeLists.txt` or `Android.mk`.

Comment: android.project->app->jni->pluginonesignal.h

Comment: can you please check and tell me, I edited the android.MK and cmakelist.txt

Comment: Your compiler expects to find the file in a directory named "PluginOneSignal". Either change the code or move the header file to a directory with that name.

Comment: I did but its showing same error is there any other option?

Comment: Then you have to ensure that `android.project/app/jni` is on the include path for your Android compilation. Edit your question with the full cmake build output.

Comment: I included  path for compilation then also its showing the same error

Comment: Edit your question so I can see what you changed and add the full error output, including the compilation command.